Wake up printer c++
We are trying to use C++ to send a command to a printer to wake it up.
We are using the Fargo HDP5000 printer sdk (fargoNativeAPI.dll).  Has anyone used this sdk?  Is it possible to send a wakeup without the SDK?  Also, I have the printer emulator running, but I can't tell if the command is being sent.   Are there low level logs on Windows to see what is happening?
try
{
    std::cout << "Loading FargoNativeAPI\n" << std::endl;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"D:/util/projects2/rapids/bin/FargoNativeAPI.dll");

    if (hinstLib != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Loaded FargoNativeAPI successfully...\n" << std::endl;

        pCreateDiagnosticsUtilW = (CreateDiagnosticsUtilW)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "CreateDiagnosticsUtilW");
        pDestroyDiagnosticsUtilW = (DestroyDiagnosticsUtil)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "DestroyDiagnosticsUtil");
        pDiagnosticsUtil_WakeUpPrinter = (DiagnosticsUtil_WakeUpPrinter)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "DiagnosticsUtil_WakeUpPrinter");
        if ((NULL != pCreateDiagnosticsUtilW) && (NULL != pDiagnosticsUtil_WakeUpPrinter))
        {
            std::cout << "Getting Printer Name...\n" << std::endl;

        
            const char* printerStr = "HDP5000 Card Printer\0";
            int bufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, printerStr, -1, NULL, 0);
            wchar_t* pPrinterName = new wchar_t[bufferSize];
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, printerStr, -1, pPrinterName, bufferSize);

            std::cout << "Done getting Printer Name...\n" << std::endl;


            pDiagnosticsUtil = (pCreateDiagnosticsUtilW)((LPWSTR)pPrinterName);

            //PVOID pDiagnosticsUtil = pCreateDiagnosticsUtilW(pPrinterName);

            std::cout << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;

            if (NULL != pDiagnosticsUtil)
            {

                pDiagnosticsUtil_WakeUpPrinter(pDiagnosticsUtil);

                std::cout << GetLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;

                pDestroyDiagnosticsUtilW(pDiagnosticsUtil);
                delete[] pPrinterName;
            }
            else
            {
                delete[] pPrinterName;
                std::cout << "Problem instantiating pDiagnostics!\n" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Problem loading FargoNativeAPI!\n" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "\nDone calling Fargo WakeUp Command";
}
catch (...)
{
    // catch any other errors (that we have no information about)
    std::cerr << "Unknown failure occurred. Possible memory corruption" << std::endl;
}


OT: Why not use L"HDP5000 Card Printer" to get a wide-character string to begin with, without needing to do the conversion and dynamic allocation?

Thanks.  You are correct, but that is temporary.  The printer name will be passed in.

Then my recommendation is to not mix narrow and wide characters. Use one or the other exclusively. It will make things much simpler.

Does the DLL have any advantages over sending data to the printer port?  It's been my experience (developing printers) that talking directly to the printer is the best method.

"Is it possible to send a wakeup without the SDK?" It depends. If it supports WOL, you could try a PoC. Here's an example. No guarantees that'll work, of course.
